# Conda dependency resolution error unintelligible

Tags: conda

Can anyone help me to understand how this is supposed to be read?  Whenever I get dependency resolution errors from Conda, I wind up just having to basically do my own investigation, because the error message (though it looks like it's really trying to be helpful) basically feels useless.

Would love to better understand how I'm supposed to read this.

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Package libffi conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> libffi[version='>=3.2.1,<3.3.0a0|>=3.2.1,<4.0a0']
Package python conflicts for:
workflow -> python
Package pip conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> pip
Package xz conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> xz[version='>=5.2.3,<5.3.0a0|>=5.2.4,<5.3.0a0|>=5.2.4,<6.0a0']
Package libstdcxx-ng conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
Package jinja2 conflicts for:
workflow -> jinja2
Package readline conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0']
Package pygraphviz conflicts for:
workflow -> pygraphviz
Package pyfunctional conflicts for:
workflow -> pyfunctional[version='>=1.2.0']
Package click conflicts for:
workflow -> click[version='>=7']
Package snakemake conflicts for:
workflow -> snakemake[version='>=5.3.0']
Package networkx conflicts for:
workflow -> networkx
Package openssl conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> openssl[version='>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2p,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a']
Package zlib conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
Package sqlite conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> sqlite[version='>=3.24.0,<4.0a0|>=3.25.1,<4.0a0|>=3.25.2,<4.0a0|>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.27.2,<4.0a0|>=3.28.0,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0|>=3.30.1,<4.0a0']
Package libgcc-ng conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=4.9|>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
Package pygments conflicts for:
workflow -> pygments
Package tk conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> tk[version='>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.9,<8.7.0a0']
Package psutil conflicts for:
workflow -> psutil[version='>=5.6.3']
Package bzip2 conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> bzip2[version='>=1.0.6,<2.0a0']
Package ncurses conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<6.2.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0']
```

Comment: I've found that most of the time it is utterly useless and completely fails to identify the underlying conflicts. On the rare exception that it works it shows at least two dependency strings (`dependent-pkg -> dependency_pkg[version constraints]`) where the version constraints are incompatible on some package. I definitely regard this "feature" as a work-in-progress.

Answer (score 1):

```
Package libffi conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> libffi[version='>=3.2.1,<3.3.0a0|']
```

I *think* this means you are trying to install python 3.7 which requires `libffi` version to be >=3.2.1 and <3.3.0a0 (or >=3.2.1 and<4.0a0). But the `libffi` version you installed in the past was required to be outside of this range of compatible versions (e.g. you required it to be <3.2).

Maybe post the command that generated the error and the output of `conda list` (assuming you are trying to install/upgrade in the current environment).

Comment: Perhaps a more useful output to include would be the YAML from `conda env export --from-history`. That would tell us explicit specs. Things that don't have explicit specs are freely adjustable (i.e., wouldn't generate a conflict), and you can't tell what is explicit in `conda list` alone.